# python difference between round and int

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point, int

I've been playing around with python for a bit now and i've noticed a strange behavior that makes me curious: what is the difference between `float(int(n))` and `round(n)`?

When should I use one, another or neither of them?

Comment: In 1st case you first cast the number to int so all digits after comma are gone then you cast again to float so for example 3.6 will result in 3.0 which is mathematically wrong. Round is mathematical round

Comment: The `round` can also take a second argument for the precision. That makes it different from the `float(int(n))`. As for the neither now, that is too broad.

Comment: Have you tried something like: `round(1.7)` and `float(int(1.7))`?

Comment: What is the strange behaviour you've noticed?

Comment: @Veltro same results for what numbers? Update the question

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**Note: The python implementation [changed](https://bugs.python.org/issue21179) between 2.7 and 3.x. I corrected the answer accordingly.**

For the sake of completeness, let me add two more functions to your question and explain the differences between `float(int(x))`, `math.floor(x)`, `round(x)` and `math.ceil(x)`.

Let's start with a question: "What integer represents best the number 1.6?"
We have two possible answers (1 and 2) but many different reasons why one answer may be better than the other one:

- `int(1.6)==1`: This is what you get when you cut off the decimals.
- `math.floor(1.6)==1`: Its less than 2.  Incomplete pieces don't count.
- `round(1.6)==2`: Because 2 is closer than 1.
- `math.ceil(1.6)==2`: Its more than 1.  When you start a part, you have to pay the full price.

Let's ask python to print a nice table of the results you get with different values of x:

```
from math import floor, ceil
tab='\t' 

print('x \tint\tfloor\tround\tceil')
for x in (
    1.0, 1.1, 1.5, 1.9, -1.1, -1.5, -1.9, 
    -2.5, -1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5,
):
    print(x, tab, int(x), tab, floor(x), tab, round(x), tab, ceil(x))
```

Here is the output:

```
x       int floor   round   ceil
1.0     1   1       1       1
1.1     1   1       1       2
1.5     1   1       2       2
1.9     1   1       2       2
-1.1    -1  -2      -1      -1
-1.5    -1  -2      -2      -1
-1.9    -1  -2      -2      -1
-2.5    -2  -3      -2      -2
-1.5    -1  -2      -2      -1
-0.5    0   -1      0       0
0.5     0   0       0       1
1.5     1   1       2       2
2.5     2   2       2       3
```

You see that no of these four functions are equal.

- `floor` rounds towards minus infinity: It chooses always the lowest possible answer:  `floor(1.99)==1` and `floor(-1.01)==-2`.
- `ceil` rounds towards infinity: It chooses always the highest possible answer: `ceil(1.01)==2` and `ceil(-1.99)=-1`.
- `int` rounds towards zero: For positive `x` it is like `floor`, for negative `x` it is like `ceil`.
- `round` rounds to the closest possible solution: `round(1.49)=1` and `round(1.51)==2`.  When `x` is precisely between two numbers, `round(x)` will be the closest *even* number. This is called **half to even rounding** or **Banker's Rounding** because it is commonly used in financial calculations.

**Note:** The python implementation [changed](https://bugs.python.org/issue21179) between 2.7 and 3.x:  Python 2.7 does not use the "half to even rounding" rule (explained above) but rounds all half-numbers away from zero: `round(1.5)==2` and `round(-1.5)==-2`.  Bankers and mathematicians who care about this agree that the "half to even rounding" rule used in 3.x is the "right way" to do it because it distributes rounding errors fairly.

Comment: Great answer.  My only nit-pick would be that programmers don't view `int(x)` as rounding, it is dropping everything after the decimal point which is technically known as `truncation` (although you are correct that the effect is identical to round-toward-zero).  Just thought I would mention this to avoid confusion with traditional concepts of rounding. (note: `int(x)` is identical to `math.trunc(x)` as long as `x` is numeric)

Comment: generally speaking: int(x) => removes the decimal/fractional part and returns the integer part of x; round() => int(x + 0.5); floor(x) => int(x); ceil(x) => int(x) + 1

Comment: @ReignBough: Watch out: **All your equations are imprecise** --- the rules are more complicated than you think: `round(0.5)==0` but `int(0.5+0.5)==1`; `floor(-1.9)==-2` but `int(-1.9)==-1`; `ceil(1)==1` but `int(1)+1==2`. Python has the four similar but subtly different functions because in different situations, you need different kinds of rounding.  I suggest you first understand the different intentions between the four functions (as explained in the answer) and then always choose the function that does what you actually want.

Comment: With Python 3.x the other option is `x // 1`, which my testing tells me behaves like `floor()`.

Comment: @DonovanBaarda -- You are right: `// 1` is `__floordiv__` which first divides by 1 (and thus returns the same number) and then applies `floor()`.

Answer (score 12):

`round(n)` is a function to round a float, `int(n)` will cast a float to an integer and will get rid of the decimal part by truncating it.

Comment: What about negative numbers?

Comment: `int(-3.6)` will give -3 and `round(-3.6)` will give -4 so still rounding for round and truncating for int().

Comment: @Veltro `float(int(n))` will have the same behaviour than int(n) but will cast it from an `int` to a `float`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not always true that round(num) will create an int. if num is numpy.float64, it does not convert to int.

```type(round(np.float64(2.000054))) returns 
<class 'numpy.float64'>
``` 
thus it is necessary to be safe and use ```int(round())``` which always works. 
For me, this is a python bug.

Comment: Not sure which version of Python you are using, but I just tested with Python 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8 and `type(round(np.float64(2.000054)))` returns `<class 'int'>`, maybe it is an issue with older versions of Python?

Answer (score 6):

`round` is a mathematical rounding and `int` just casts to an integer, essentially truncating the value.

Take 2 variables:

```
var1 = 5.5
var2 = 5.1
```

If we round them

```
round(var1)
round(var2)
```

We get 6.0 and 5.0 respectively.

However, if we just cast them to an int

```
int(var1)
int(var2)
```

We get 5 for both of them.

You can test this out yourself in the python interpreter.

Comment: Note: `round()` without a second argument returns an `int` in Py3

Comment: The question was tagged python2, so I didn't check python3..but I didn't actually know that, so thanks (I still use mostly python 2 on a daily basis)

Comment: What about negative numbers?

Comment: That's another difference to note then. Unlike in maths and python2, python3 ```round``` rounds down ```4.5```, which makes it essentially the same as casting to an ```int```

Comment: Yes, there is a difference between mathematical rounding and python rounding, in that python's `round()` will prefer the `even` number for 2 equally distance results, `round(4.5) -> 4` and `round(3.5) -> 4`. Note also: as per the documentation "the behavior of round() for floats can be surprising" - a limitation of floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Perhaps that's the strange behaviour OP mentioned?