# Which stage to round at?

Tags: python, rounding

In Python, at what stage should `round` be used? Take this example: `10 * math.log(x) + 10` If I want this to be rounded which should I use?

```
round(10 * math.log(x) + 5)
round(10 * math.log(x)) + 5
10 * round(math.log(x)) + 5
```

My guess would be that rounding early would run the fastest because more arithmetic happens with integers, which seem like they should be faster than floats. Rounding seems less likely to break if some later values change.

Would the answer be the same with `int()`?

Comment: If the result of `math.log(x)` is `0.5`, do you want `10 * math.log(x)` to be `0` or `5`?

Comment: Why is speed ever a criteria here? The domain you use this is, is important. If you are on the 100th floor of a building, would you step out of the windows because its faster then using the elevator? At least here the outcome if (kinda) the same, you are on the 1st floor - aDlEiAvDe

Comment: Your expressions are not equivalent. Accuracy rather than microbenchmarking should be your criteria.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this without understanding *why* you're rounding in the first place. What's the intent? How is the rounded value going to be used? (Often, the answer to "when to round?" is either "never!", or "only when displaying a result to the user", and in the latter case you want to be using string formatting, not the `round` builtin function.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't prematurely optimize. In many cases, it's *not* highly optimized mathematical functions which slow down programs, but the *logic*, *structure* or *data types* used in the calculation.

To that end, I recommend you use [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/profile.html) to identify bottlenecks. Note that cProfile itself has an overhead, so it is mostly useful for relative comparisons.

As per @glibdud's comment, you have to understand how rounding will affect your calculation. Try a few examples, or perform a test to see how your error may vary across a large number of inputs.

Comment: +1 for not prematurely optimizing. The logic behind why would want to implement this change is much more important that the very small gain in performance you might see.

Answer (score 1):

The earlier you are rounding, the more your result will be affected by this rounding. In my opinion, it all depends on the expectations of your program.

As for the [difference between int() and round()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43660910/python-difference-between-round-and-int), this thread answers it perfectly.

To be more specific to your question about performance : The `round()` function, that is a python built-in, is implemented in C, and you shouldn't really worry about performance as it will be **very, very** negligible.

[Round function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round)

Answer (score 1):

That entirely depends upon how you want your answer to be formatted and interpreted. I would not be hung up on the speed of the round function though (unless the very minor performance gain is **crucial** to your program). I would think about what I'm trying to accomplish by rounding. If your goal is to produce an output that is rounded to the nearest integer (for simplicity) then I would encompass your entire arithmetic statement into the round function. If your goal is to only use rounded integers in your log calculations (maybe because you don't want to use floats) then you should only round the math.log(x) function. There is no technical reason why you would use either, but there is definitely a logical reason that you would want to choose either of your options.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the Python Math.log() function is the base of e by default. By your questions it's unclear what base you expect so I'll assume log base of 10 like Google does. In order to make it equivalent to the mathematical function provided the code would need to be:

```
import math
#assuming x equals 2
x = 2
function1 = round(10 * math.log(x,10) + 5)
function2 = round(10 * math.log(x,10)) + 5)
function3 = 10 * round(math.log(x,10)) + 5)
function4 = 10*math.log(x,10)+5

print(function1)
print(function2)
print(function3)
print(function4)
```

Now, assuming x = 2, the calculations for the mathematical equation is **8.01029995664**
Looking at the printed output from the above code:

```
8
8
5
8.010299956639813
```

It clearly shows that functions 1,2 and 4 are roughly mathematically equivalent with function 3 being incorrect. This is because the round function uses Half and Above rule to round up. Math.log(2,10) results in 0.3, so when the round function happens it drops to zero.

As for the equivalence of int() and round() the link referenced by IMCoins is pretty good. The summation is that int() removes decimal values from a number and the round uses the half and above rule so it will act like the int() for anything less than x.5.

As for the speed question, if accuracy is non-negotiable it would be best to round upon completion of the answer due to the same reasons as why function 3 was wrong above. If you're fairly certain you can round safely at a step, then I agree with the answer above to use CProfile and find the bottlenecks

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't see any indication that the OP wanted log base 10 rather than natural log, so your use of `math.log(x, 10)` seem unjustified.

Comment: True it may be unjustified since there was no indication of what base he wanted. Because I didn't calculate it by hand, I verified the answer using Google who assumes base 10. Thus I changed it. I'll edit the wording to reflect this

Comment: I like the answer here (and I voted up!), because of the way it's addressing the 2 parts in the question with examples. The question is really confusing, no matter how do you round, how could you get close result for `10 * math.log(x) + 10` with those formulas... No wonder people doubt the base. But! After reading this answer, I have realized, oh, the question is asking the speed :)

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue, but let's see :)

```
import time
import math

n = 1000000
x = 5

def timeit(f):

    t_0 = time.perf_counter()

    for _ in range(n):
        f()

    t_1 = time.perf_counter()

    print((t_1 - t_0)/ n)        

def fun1():
    round(10 * math.log(x) + 5)

def fun2():
    round(10 * math.log(x)) + 5

def fun3():
    10 * round(math.log(x)) + 5    

[timeit(_) for _ in [fun1, fun2, fun3]]
```

On my computer the last one is slightly faster than the others.

Comment: I could not gain consistent results with this test. Each run had varying performances and each function performed better at times than the other two.

Comment: Depending on the order in the list?

Comment: What do you mean? The results were mixed with the first item in the list sometimes being greater than the rest and sometimes being less than. I'm saying the neither of the functions seem to perform consistently better.

Comment: Any ideas how to test that in a reliable way?

Comment: I think your test is fine, my point is that the ordering of the round() function makes little to no difference